# Voxeet UXKit Cordova - Cant install cordova plugin missing "Carthage/Build/VoxeetUXKit.xcframework

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I use this plugin for a cordova app and I didn`t ahve any problem on Android platform, is working as expected but Ican't install it on IOS. After cordova-install I get:

```
Error: Command failed: /Users/interalia/Documents/Alexini Project/WorkoutMinister/WorkoutMinister/plugins/cordova-plugin-voxeet/carthage.sh update --use-xcframeworks --platform ios --no-use-binaries --project-directory /Users/interalia/Documents/Alexini Project/WorkoutMinister/WorkoutMinister/plugins/cordova-plugin-voxeet/src/ios
/bin/sh: /Users/interalia/Documents/Alexini: No such file or directory
```

And then

```
Cannot find framework "/Users/interalia/Documents/Alexini Project/WorkoutMinister/WorkoutMinister/plugins/cordova-plugin-voxeet/src/ios/Carthage/Build/VoxeetUXKit.xcframework" for plugin cordova-plugin-voxeet in iOS platform
```

Im using cordova 11.0.0 and xcode Version 12.5.1 (12E507)

Thanks for the help

Comment: You have space in your path: .../Alexini Project/... try to read the error: /bin/sh: /Users/interalia/Documents/Alexini: No such file or directory shell was trying to open file Alexini, which doesn't exists

Comment: I was able to solve this using sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer on the path. Maybe the space wasn't the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it installing xcode 13 and then going to the cordova project root folder and running

`sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

after that I was able install it.